# What is the issue with double free()?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, free, undefined-behavior

I've been seeing quite a bit of erroneous code around the web and in my Advanced C class (such as the code below). While I understand that it's obviously bad coding practice, I'm having a difficult time as to what it does that's so bad other than waste CPU cycles. From my understanding so far, if a pointer allocation is not located in the "malloc table" (for lack of a better word), it is usually ignored. I'd appreciate if someone here could provide me with a better understanding as to why this is bad and (other than the fact that it's a silly thing to do) and the consequences of it are.

```
char* ptr = malloc(1);

...

free(ptr);
...
free(ptr);
```

Comment: It is simply *undefined behaviour*. This means your program could not be considered to "work". There isn't much to understand here.

Comment: If you want a specific badness beyond general undefined behaviour: what if another call to `malloc` after the first `free` returned the same address?

Comment: ^ I don't get it :S.. What's so bad about that?  `malloc, free, malloc, free`? Looks legit to me even if the two calls to malloc return the exact same address.. I can't think of anything wrong :S

Comment: @Brandon: I meant another, independent, call to `malloc`, by some unrelated code managing its own memory. If it happened to get the same address as this one, then that would be unexpectedly freed by the erroneous second `free` here, leaving it with a dangling pointer.

Comment: What if you're on an OS which in turn does not allow a double deallocation and `malloc`'s implementation releases memory ASAP?  It works this way because it is the more sensible option.  Why should `malloc` do your bookkeeping for you?  Also for the reason that @MikeSeymour mentioned. It just leads to complications.  Why would you chose a more complicated and error prone standard?

Comment: "a pointer allocation is not located in the "malloc table" (for lack of a better word), it is usually ignored." This statement is meaningless. Define "usually".

Comment: Efficient management of malloc pools is quite complex and there's no telling what damage might occur in any given implementation from freeing a block that was already freed. Your assumption that it is harmless is entirely baseless.

Comment: @n.m. I wrote the same thing and then decided not to get into it, but that's a complete mishmash of words. What's "a pointer allocation"? How can such a thing be "located in the malloc table", and what the heck is *that*? I suppose the OP means the free list, but that contains blocks, not pointers. And what does it mean to ignore "a pointer allocation" and how would such a thing be implemented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good advise: nullify pointer after free. In your case you have undefined behaviour, because computer can allocate memory, which is pointed by ptr, or may not allocate this piece of memory, or this chunk of memory could be added to other chunk of memory during defragmentation, etc.
On the other hand, free(NULL) is defined and will do nothing.

```
char* ptr = malloc(1);
...
free(ptr);
ptr = NULL;
...
free(ptr);
```

Comment: Ah, I did not know that free(NULL) is defined. I like that explination.

Comment: It's strange that this was chosen as the accepted answer. Whether or not setting freed pointers to NULL is good practice, that and free(NULL) aren't relevant to the question.

Answer (score 15):

Consider in your example after free(ptr) you did following

```
char* ptr = malloc(1);

free(ptr) // <-- This will delete the pointer
ptr2 = malloc(1) // <-- now you request again
```

now malloc is what it is and *can* return the same pointer as ptr and if it does and if now you do

```
// if you call me again and if ptr2 == ptr oops!
free(ptr)
```

-- your ptr2 is freed causing unexpected behavior with lots of crash, pain and hours of debugging..

Comment: This is very useful and I understand the concern.  What I still want to know is why does `ptr` even have a value?  The second time you call `free(ptr)` what value does `ptr` have at this point?  I'm referring to the example where we don't set it to `NULL` specifically...so, after `free(ptr)`, what is `ptr` now?  I'm somewhat of a noob.  Still missing the finer points (or the _basics_), I guess.

Comment: @harperville At the time of the second `free` call, `ptr` will have the same value that it had at the time of the first `free` call. The value of `ptr` does not change after a call to `free`.

Answer (score 7):

This is not just a waste of CPU cycles. Double `free()` is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which means that the program is allowed to behave in arbitrary ways.

The program might work just fine, or it might blow up in testing, or it might pass all your tests and then blow up in your customer's face, or it might corrupt some data, or it might launch a nuclear strike, etc. All of these are valid manifestations of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 7):

C11, section 7.22.3.3 says that:

> [...] Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
>   function, or **if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, the behavior is undefined**.